# Use Apache Beam as dependency

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use Apache Beam either as Maven or Gradle dependency. As I know the project is incubating as intended to be a evolved version of Google Dataflow SDK.

So, I might be making a wrong assumption: as I haven't found across the initial documentation from Apache Beam's project, how could I use their Java sdk version as a Gradle or Maven dependency on my project? I haven't found what is the exactly artifactid, groupid to add. Anyone here already used it?

Comment: This is a very old question. Apache Beam has evolved into an apache project and runs in other runners than Google Dataflow. The dependencies can be found in Maven. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Beam hasn't released its first version yet, so its binaries aren't  available in the Maven Central Repository just yet.

The first release, `0.1.0-incubating`, has just been [started](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-beam-dev/201606.mbox/%3CCAMdX749_-_kx8qkzEynZ3umOhiUho0CHpX1Ft70mZOjBY9MrBg%40mail.gmail.com%3E) yesterday and should be released shortly. At that point, Apache Beam binaries will be available in the Maven Central Repository and will be searchable [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.apache.beam.*).

In addition, Apache Beam publishes nightly builds to Apache Software Foundation's [snapshot repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/beam/). You can also choose to take a dependency on those artifacts from build tools like Maven.

Comment: Thnkx @davor for the information. Also, I noticed [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM/component/12328909/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:component-summary-panel) the version `0.2.0-incubating` is due to be released soon. Interesting I'm gonna consider the nightly builds for now.

Comment: FYI, `0.1.0-incubating` is now released and available here: http://beam.incubator.apache.org/releases/

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is little outdated. But still for beginners you can easily find the Apache Beam Java Dependency sdk for all the build tools like maven, Gradle etc. The link is given below.

[Find it Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-core/0.4.0)